Is there a more efficient way to replace multiple different strings in a file using Python? i.e. loop/function etc?
I have a python script that looks at output of a txt file as per below but where currently I am performing the same thing multiple times, I don't know if this is a limitation or it could be made more efficient. There are quite a few strings that need replacing but will just put a few below:
############################################################### Replace string1

f = open('/home/dir/example.txt', 'r')
filedata = f.read()
f.close()

formatFileStatus1 = filedata.replace("string1", "newstring1")
f = open('/home/dir/example.txt', 'w')
f.write(formatFileStatus1)
f.close()

############################################################### Replace string2

f = open('/home/dir/example.txt', 'r')
filedata = f.read()
f.close()


formatFileStatus2 = filedata.replace("string2", "newstring2")
f = open('/home/dir/example.txt', 'w')
f.write(formatFileStatus2)
f.close()

############################################################### Replace string3

f = open('/home/dir/example.txt', 'r')
filedata = f.read()
f.close()

formatFileStatus3 = filedata.replace("string3", "newstring3")
f = open('/home/dir/example.txt', 'w')
f.write(formatFileStatus3)
f.close()


Do all the replacements to the same filedata string, not by reading and writing the file repeatedly.

Why are you even writing and reading each time instead of doing all the replaces at once?

It is worth looking at the flashtext module which can be used for once-through multiple replacements.

Note that unless you have very specific requirements, which can't be seen here, you are likely to be better off doing the replacement with unix utilities such as "sed"  or "awk" which exist solely for text manipulation, such as sed -i "s/string3/newstring3/g" /home/dir/example.txt
